requests on django api by javascript with CORS error
I have a web application for many years that uses Django and Django Rest Framework. The API is used by a python application and it works correctly:
import requests
response = requests.options(http://example.com/api/albums/)
200
{'name': 'Album List List', 'description': '', 'renders': ['application/json', 'text/html'], 'parses': ['application/json', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data'], 'actions': {'POST': ....

I discovered Svelte and I wanted to work with this API but impossible:
let api_ = "http://example.com/api/albums/"
const getAlbums = async () => {
    var response = await fetch(api, {
        mode: 'cors', method: 'GET', headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
    var result = await response.json();
    return result.results;
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The “Same Origin” policy does not allow viewing the remote resource located at http://example.com/api/albums/. Reason: The “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” CORS header is missing. Status Code: 200.

I read that you need to install django-cors-headers. but now I have this error:
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 174, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 69, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 174, in get_package_libraries
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    module = import_module(entry[1])
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/templates.py", line 10, in check_templates
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 17, in <module>
    for engine in engines.all():
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in all
    from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py)
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/django_blog/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    main()
File "/home/vianney/Documents/django_blog/manage.py", line 18, in main
    engine = engine_cls(params)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 26, in __init__
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    options["libraries"] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 88, in get_templatetag_libraries
    utility.execute()
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 162, in get_installed_libraries
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    return {
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 162, in <dictcomp>
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 75, in execute
    return {
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 151, in get_template_tag_modules
    super().execute(*args, **options)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 459, in execute
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 176, in get_package_libraries
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in handle
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py)
    self.run(**options)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 119, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 671, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 660, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 343, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 189, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 50, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 16, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 94, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 26, in __init__
    options["libraries"] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 88, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 162, in get_installed_libraries
    return {
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 162, in <dictcomp>
    return {
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 151, in get_template_tag_modules
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
File "/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 176, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/home/vianney/Documents/.blog/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py)

my Python version is 3.10.12, Django is 5.1.2 and Rest Framework is 3.12.4 and I installed the Cors Unlocked add-on under firefox.
does anyone have an explanation? why with python I have access to my api and not with javascript?
thank you for your help.

This question is similar to: Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can replace "Postman" with any other non-browser client, e.g. Python.

thanks for this answer @jabaa. but my problem is that Django-cors-headers does not install on my version of django even with deletion of my VENV.

No, your question is "does anyone have an explanation? why with python I have access to my api and not with javascript?" I can't find any other questions. If that's not your actual question, either edit this question or ask a new one.

This issue is closer to being compatibility issue. Make sure you're using the right django version. for instance this two are compatible
django==4.2.9 djangorestframework==3.14.0
